# Связанные списки Ajax

Tags: javascript

Как сделать так, чтобы второй список изменялся моментально, в зависимости от выбранного `<option>` в первом?
Это файл, в котором выводятся списки:

```
    <select id="country">
    <option value="us">Америка</option>
    <option value="ru">Россия</option>
    </select>
    <script>
    var country = $("#country").val();
            $.ajax({
      type: 'GET',      
      url: 'city.php',
      data: 'id='+country,
      success: function(data) {
        $('#city').html(data);
      }
    });
        </script>
<select id="city">

</select>
```

Это `city.php`:

```
<?php 
        $country= $_GET['id'];
        $city=mysql_query("select id,name from $country ORDER BY id ASC ");

         if ($course){
            while($data=mysql_fetch_array($course))
                {
                    echo '<option value="'.$data[0].'">'.$data[1].'</option>';
                }
         }
         else{
            echo '<option">Нет городов</option>';
         }
?>
```

Выводится только первый, а при изменении `<option>` ничего не происходит.

Comment: нужно обернуть функцию запроса в обработчик _change_ для первого селекта

Comment: А можно пример ?

Comment: да, конечно можно.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для того, что при изменении выбора в одном списке, что-то происходило в другом, необходимо подписаться на событие изменения [*change*](https://api.jquery.com/change/).
Так как в коде уже используется *`$.ajax`* пример приведу для jQuery

```
<select id="country">
    <option value="us">Америка</option>
    <option value="ru">Россия</option>
</select>
<script>
    $("#country").change(function(){//подписываемся на событие
        //var country = $("#country").val();
        //следующая строка эквивалентна предыдущей, так как this в обработчике указывает на HTML элемент
        var country = $(this).val();
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',      
            url: 'city.php',
            data: 'id='+country,
            success: function(data) {
                $('#city').html(data);
            }
        });
    });

</script>
<select id="city">

</select>
```

Comment: Просто нечеловеческое СПАСИБО))))